# Assigning variables to tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to assign a variable to a table, as shown below:

```
b = {x = 3, y = 4}

a = b
-- Reassigning by value?
a.x = 10
print(b.x,b.y)
--OUTPUT: 10 4
```

However, what I expected was that b.x should not be changed at all, as I had only changed the value of a.x, so it seems that I don't quite understand what the "a=b" in this example is actually doing.

Sorry if this is a basic question, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

the problem is that `a=b` causes them to point at the same table, as seen from the repl-output below.

```
> c = {x = 10, y = 3}
> c
table: 0x564bbdb2d420
> b = c
> b
table: 0x564bbdb2d420
> c
table: 0x564bbdb2d420
```

You'd need a deep copy, such as this (taken from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tylerneylon/81333721109155b2d244)):

```
function copy3(obj, seen)
  -- Handle non-tables and previously-seen tables.
  if type(obj) ~= 'table' then return obj end
  if seen and seen[obj] then return seen[obj] end

  -- New table; mark it as seen an copy recursively.
  local s = seen or {}
  local res = setmetatable({}, getmetatable(obj))
  s[obj] = res
  for k, v in pairs(obj) do res[copy3(k, s)] = copy3(v, s) end
  return res
end
```

which is used like this `a = copy3(b)`